# Haskell GHCi - Using EOF character on stdin with getContents

Tags: haskell, multiline, ghci

I like to parse strings ad hoc in Python by just pasting into the interpreter.

```
>>> s = """Adams, John
... Washington,George
... Lincoln,Abraham
... Jefferson, Thomas
... """
>>> print "\n".join(x.split(",")[1].replace(" ", "")
                    for x in s.strip().split("\n"))
John
George
Abraham
Thomas
```

This works great using the Python interpreter, but I'd like to do this with Haskell/GHCi.  Problem is, I can't paste multi-line strings.  I can use getContents with an EOF character, but I can only do it once since the EOF character closes stdin.

```
Prelude> s <- getContents
Prelude> s
"Adams, John
Adams, John\nWashington,George
Washington,George\nLincoln,Abraham
Lincoln,Abraham\nJefferson, Thomas
Jefferson, Thomas\n^Z
"
Prelude> :{
Prelude| putStr $ unlines $ map ((filter (`notElem` ", "))
Prelude|                         . snd . (break (==','))) $ lines s
Prelude| :}
John
George
Abraham
Thomas
Prelude> x <- getContents
*** Exception: <stdin>: hGetContents: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

Is there a better way to go about doing this with GHCi?  Note - my understanding of getContents (and Haskell IO in general) is probably severely broken.

**UPDATED**

I will be playing with the answers I have received.  Here are some helper functions I made (plagiarized) that simulate Python's `"""` quoting (by ending with `"""`, not starting) from ephemient's answer.

```
getLinesWhile :: (String -> Bool) -> IO String
getLinesWhile p = liftM unlines $ takeWhileM p (repeat getLine)

getLines :: IO String
getLines = getLinesWhile (/="\"\"\"")
```

To use AndrewC's answer in GHCi -

```
C:\...\code\haskell> ghci HereDoc.hs -XQuasiQuotes
ghci> :{
*HereDoc| let s = [heredoc|
*HereDoc| Adams, John
*HereDoc| Washington,George
*HereDoc| Lincoln,Abraham
*HereDoc| Jefferson, Thomas
*HereDoc| |]
*HereDoc| :}
ghci> putStrLn s
Adams, John
Washington,George
Lincoln,Abraham
Jefferson, Thomas
ghci> :{
*HereDoc| putStr $ unlines $ map ((filter (`notElem` ", "))
*HereDoc|                         . snd . (break (==','))) $ lines s
*HereDoc| :}
John
George
Abraham
Thomas
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getContents` == `hGetContents stdin`.  Unfortunately, `hGetContents` marks its handle as (semi-)closed, which means anything attempting to read from `stdin` ever again will fail.

Does it suffice to simply read up to an empty line or some other marker, never closing `stdin`?

```
takeWhileM :: Monad m => (a -> Bool) -> [m a] -> m [a]
takeWhileM p (ma : mas) = do
    a <- ma
    if p a
      then liftM (a :) $ takeWhileM p mas
      else return []
takeWhileM _ _ = return []
```

```
ghci> liftM unlines $ takeWhileM (not . null) (repeat getLine)
Adams, John
Washington, George
Lincoln, Abraham
Jefferson, Thomas

"Adams, John\nWashington, George\nLincoln, Abraham\nJefferson, Thomas\n"
ghci>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'd like to know how to open a handle to stdin manually on Windows.  Either way, this will work for now.  I've made some helper functions based on your answer (updated in my question).

Answer (score 2):

If you do this a lot, and you're writing helper functions in some module anyway, why not go the whole hog and use your editor for the raw data too:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes #-}
module ParseAdHoc where
import HereDoc
import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.List (intercalate,intersperse)  -- other handy helpers

-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- edit this bit every time you do your ad-hoc parsing

adhoc :: String -> String
adhoc = head . splitOn ',' . rmspace

input = [heredoc|
Adams, John
Washington,George
Lincoln,Abraham
Jefferson, Thomas
|]

-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- add other helpers you'll reuse here

main = mapM_ putStrLn.map adhoc.lines $ input

rmspace = filter (not.isSpace)

splitWith :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]   -- splits using a function that tells you when
splitWith isSplitter list =  case dropWhile isSplitter list of
  [] -> []
  thisbit -> firstchunk : splitWith isSplitter therest
    where (firstchunk, therest) = break isSplitter thisbit

splitOn :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]       -- splits on the given item
splitOn c = splitWith (== c)

splitsOn :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]    -- splits on any of the given items
splitsOn chars = splitWith (`elem` chars)
```

It would be easier to use `takeWhile (/=',')` instead of `head . splitOn ','`, but I thought that `splitOn` will be more useful to you in the future.

This uses a helper module, HereDoc, that lets you paste multiline string literals into your code (like perl's `<<"EOF"` or python's `"""`). I can't remember how I found how to do this, but I've tweaked it to remove whitespace first and last lines, so I can start and end my data with a newline.

```
module HereDoc where
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Data.Char (isSpace)

{-
example1 = [heredoc|Hi.
This is a multi-line string.
It should appear as an ordinary string literal.

Remember you can only use a QuasiQuoter
in a different module, so import this HereDoc module 
into something else and don't forget the
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, QuasiQuotes #-}|]

example2 = [heredoc|         
This heredoc has no newline characters in it because empty or whitespace-only first and last lines are ignored
                   |]
-}


heredoc = QuasiQuoter {quoteExp = stringE.topAndTail,
                       quotePat = litP . stringL,
                       quoteType = undefined,
                       quoteDec = undefined}

topAndTail = myunlines.tidyend.tidyfront.lines

tidyfront :: [String] -> [String]
tidyfront [] = []
tidyfront (xs:xss) | all isSpace xs = xss
                   | otherwise      = xs:xss

tidyend :: [String] -> [String]
tidyend [] = []
tidyend [xs]     | all isSpace xs = []
                 | otherwise = [xs]
tidyend (xs:xss) = xs:tidyend xss

myunlines :: [String] -> String
myunlines [] = ""
myunlines (l:ls) = l ++ concatMap ('\n':) ls
```

You might find Data.Text a good source of (inspiration for) helper functions:
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html