# How can I read mutiple lines from stdin within GHCI more than once?

Tags: haskell

In contrast to the information in "learn you a haskell", on my windows system, ghci translates `CTRL-D` to `EOT`, not `EOF`.

Thus, when I do something like:

```
input <- getContents
doSomething input
```

, where `doSomething` is a function which consumes the input.
Doing that, I have to press `CTRL-Z` to end my input text, which makes sense since `getContents` is intended for process piping...

But if I repeat the above steps a second time, it fails because `stdin` is closed.

So, while browsing [System.IO](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-IO.html), I could not find an alternative to `getContents`, which would react on `EOT`.

Do I have to write such a function myself or is it to be found in another package, maybe?

Btw, the version of GHCI, I use is `8.2.2`.
Also, I do not want single line processing. I am aware of `getLine` but it is not what I want in this case.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. What you're asking for is sufficiently weird (in that I've never seen a program act this way) that it's not really something that fits in a standard library. Lots of older command line applications used a single `.` on one line as a multiline text terminator, so you could do _that_ if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Cubic Not that weird obviously as "Learn you a haskell for the greater good" web site shows examples (which do not work) and given that you still have to type ``:{`` etc. for multiline input in ghci instead of simply typing away until ``CTRL-D``. In the meantime I looked at github for the source of ``getContents`` and see that it is mapped to ``primGetContents``. Any idea where I can find the source code for that?

Comment: I think this is a valid question, just ran into the same problem. On the python command line, calling `sys.stdin.read()` just works. I assume the problem is with GHCI substituting EOT for EOF, which may be to work around `getContents` semi-closing the handle on EOF, compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119420/haskell-ghci-using-eof-character-on-stdin-with-getcontents.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function I was looking for:

```
getContentsEOT :: IO String
getContentsEOT = 
    getChar >>= \c -> 
        if c == '\EOT' 
            then return "" 
            else getContentsEOT >>= \s -> 
                return (c:s)
```